# show/hide button not working

Tags: html, css

I am creating a php page which shows mcq questions with options and answers from database. Here i am using a html button for show/hide answers. but its working only for the first question but while clicking on other questions it works for the first question only. kindly help

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>


<?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<h4 style=font-weight:bold; text-align:justify>";
            echo "Q $row[slno]) $row[question]";
            echo "</h4><br>";
            echo "<ul class=list-group>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>1) $row[option1]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>2) $row[option2]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>3) $row[option3]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>4) $row[option4]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>5) $row[option5]</li>";
            echo "<div id=myDIV style=display:none><li class=list-group-item><b>Correct Option : ($row[correct_option])</b></div></li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item><button onclick=myFunction()>View Answer</button></li>";
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "<hr color=#FF0000 size=5 width=100%>";
        }
    ?>
```

Any suggestions...

Comment: you can only give the myDIV id once.. how about changing it to class?

Comment: can u pls elaborate with example. it will be great  thnx bro

Comment: It's not working because you don't have quotes around your classes and ids... <ul class=list-group> should be <ul class='list-group'>

Comment: your div is in a while loop.. so when it loops it also create a div with an ID of myDIV try changing it to class..`class=myDIV` instead of `id=myDIV`.. and change it to get elementbyCLass

Comment: used quotes Adriani6 but still not working bro...just checked

Comment: Generate dynamic ids (instead of "myDiv"), and add it as parameter of myFunction.

Comment: Shadow Fiend..........changed id to class. but now show/hide is not working totally

Comment: RoD.........how to generate dynamic ids and add it as parameter to myFunction.........can u help me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 <script>
    function myFunction(num) {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV'+num);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
    </script>


<?php
  $num=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<h4 style=font-weight:bold; text-align:justify>";
            echo "Q $row[slno]) $row[question]";
            echo "</h4><br>";
            echo "<ul class=list-group>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>1) $row[option1]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>2) $row[option2]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>3) $row[option3]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>4) $row[option4]</li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item>5) $row[option5]</li>";
            echo "<div id=myDIV".$num." style=display:none><li class=list-group-item><b>Correct Option : ($row[correct_option])</b></div></li>";
            echo "<li class=list-group-item><button onclick=myFunction('".$num."')>View Answer</button></li>";
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "<hr color=#FF0000 size=5 width=100%>";
          $num++;
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: ya its working dude...........thnx thnx thnx a lot..........u saved my day

Comment: @JahangirAlam Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your Id must be unique for each records.

```
<script>
function myFunction(elem) {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV'+elem);
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>


<?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<h4 style=font-weight:bold; text-align:justify>";
        echo "Q $row[slno]) $row[question]";
        echo "</h4><br>";
        echo "<ul class=list-group>";
        echo "<li class=list-group-item>1) $row[option1]</li>";
        echo "<li class=list-group-item>2) $row[option2]</li>";
        echo "<li class=list-group-item>3) $row[option3]</li>";
        echo "<li class=list-group-item>4) $row[option4]</li>";
        echo "<li class=list-group-item>5) $row[option5]</li>";
        echo "<div id=myDIV'".$row['slno']."' style=display:none><li class=list-group-item><b>Correct Option : ($row[correct_option])</b></div></li>";
        echo "<li class=list-group-item><button onclick=myFunction('".$row['slno']."')>View Answer</button></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "<hr color=#FF0000 size=5 width=100%>";
    }
?>
```